# Lanterna - How to make a TextBox scroll to the bottom upon adding more text

Tags: java, lanterna

I am creating a basic terminal chat application in Java using Lanterna. I have a `TextBox` component that I call `addLine()` on as new messages come in. The default behavior of a `TextBox` appears to be to maintain its previous scroll position until the user focuses on it and scrolls manually. I would like for the `TextBox` itself to scroll to the bottom automatically.

There is no obvious way to set the scroll position of a `TextBox` programmatically, so my best idea was to extend `TextBox` and make my own version of `addLine()`:

```
import com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalSize;
import com.googlecode.lanterna.gui2.TextBox;

public class ChatWindowTextBox extends TextBox{
    public ChatWindowTextBox(TerminalSize preferredSize, Style style){
        super(preferredSize, style);
    }

    public ChatWindowTextBox addLineAndScrollDown(String line){
        addLine(line);
        setReadOnly(false); // I make the chat window read only
                            // in my screen setup, so I undo that
        takeFocus();
        setCaretPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        setReadOnly(true);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Via debugging, I have verified that the arguments to `setCaretPosition` get correctly clamped to the actual values of the last line and column, and the internal value of `caretPosition` is updated to those values. However, this does not make the `TextBox` scroll. Have I misunderstood how `setCaretPosition()` behaves, and is there a viable way to programmatically make a `TextBox` scroll to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I found is to force the program to pause before making the `ChatWindowTextBox` read-only again:

```
public ChatWindowTextBox addLineAndScrollDown(String line){
    super.addLine(line);
    setReadOnly(false);
    takeFocus();
    setCaretPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setReadOnly(true);
    return this;
}
```

15 ms is about the smallest pause that allows the `ChatWindowTextBox` to scroll as expected. You may want to go for 20 or 30 ms.

The primary problem with the original code has to do with making the `ChatWindowTextBox` read-only. The solution proposed in the question actually works perfectly for `TextBox`es that are not made read-only.

Digging into Lanterna's source code, the caret position of a `TextBox` is not taken into account if it was set to read-only. However, the code in the question would appear to account for this by unsetting `readOnly`, changing the caret position, then resetting `readOnly`. So why is there unexpected behavior? Internally, `readOnly()` also calls `invalidate()`, which according to Lanterna, "Marks the component as invalid and requiring to be drawn at next opportunity." I assume that the `ChatWindowTextBox` being invalidated and soon redrawn causes the change in caret position to not completely go through before it is made read-only again.